# clang-format regex syntax reference

Tags: regex, clang-format

I want clang-format to not modify comment lines I use to separate functions from each other. I think `commentPragmas` is the right option for that, but I can't find info on the clang-format regex format.

I tried `commentPragmas: '^/\*-.*'` to capture my separator lines that look like this

`/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/`

But the above regex did not work... Where can I look up the syntax for regexes for clang-format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **TL/DR:** The flavor is POSIX ERE

---

As far as I can tell, the regex flavor isn't documented in [ClangFormat docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), that's pretty unhelpful.

Let's dig into the source code to find out.

There's a class named `ContinuationIndenter`, which has a `CommentPragmasRegex` field, of type... `llvm::Regex` [right here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/00d311a51369c41efbdae2e4935713fa10bb0e91/lib/Format/ContinuationIndenter.h#L145). Well, that's not really helpful either but maybe it's just a wrapper...

Turns out `llvm::Regex` [is a wrapper](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/8f3f50aeef0afa4b74d51713963d42b6dd9f22ae/include/llvm/Support/Regex.h#L97) around... `llvm_regex`. The header includes [this comment](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/8f3f50aeef0afa4b74d51713963d42b6dd9f22ae/include/llvm/Support/Regex.h#L10-L13) though:

> This file implements a POSIX regular expression matcher.  Both Basic and
>   Extended POSIX regular expressions (ERE) are supported.  EREs were extended
>   to support backreferences in matches.
>   This implementation also supports matching strings with embedded NUL chars.

In the [header that defines `llvm_regex`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/93e6e5414ded14bcbb233baaaa5567132fee9a0c/lib/Support/regex_impl.h#L2) we can also find this comment:

> This code is derived from OpenBSD's libc/regex

Comment: Thanks. However if I am not overlooking something my regex is compliant with posix ere, is it not? Because then I have to look for a different reason why this is not working.

Comment: Yes your pattern looks OK. I don't know ClangFormat so I'm not sure I can help further, but if I was to accuse something it would be the `^` - is it set to match on every line by default?

Comment: I already tried with and without, made no difference :/ But thanks anyway, I'll keep experimenting.