# Why does "[\\s\\S]" not working in C++11's regex

Tags: regex, c++11

I have the code below this:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::string s = "_apple_";

  std::regex r1("_(\\s|\\S)+_");
  std::regex r2("_[\\s\\S]+_");
  std::regex r3("_.+_");
  std::regex r4("_[pale]+_");

  std::smatch sm;
  printf("r1:%d r2:%d r3:%d r4:%d\n", 
        std::regex_match(s, sm, r1), 
        std::regex_match(s, sm, r2), 
        std::regex_match(s, sm, r3), 
        std::regex_match(s, sm, r4));

  return 0;
}
```

output:r1:1 r2:0 r3:1 r4:1

I can not understand why r2 is not match?

My environment is:

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin.

Comment: Interesting.  On a GCC compiler, [your code is working as expected](https://rextester.com/GCZSD11422).

Comment: but it does not work on my computer.

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Then maybe shorthands like `\s` and `\S` cannot be used in character classes in your flavor of C++.  In any case, your first regex given is a suitable workaround.  But +1 to your good question.

Comment: I test the code on Mac, Ubuntu and Windows.
It works as expected on Ubuntu and Windows. So I guess \s and \S cannot be used in character classes under Apple LLVM or it maybe a bug. I am not sure.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the OS, so much as the version of C++ you are using.

Comment: yes, i agree with you. the issue is not the os. I guess the issue is compiler.

Comment: @user1927896 Can you please provide a link to the compiler reference?

Answer (score 0):

The clang regex flavor is POSIX ERE acc. to [clang-format regex syntax reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986692/3832970). In [POSIX *bracket expressions*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), the usual regex escape sequences, like `\s`, `\d`, `\w`, and even `\]`, are not supported.

The `[\s\S]` is the same as `[\\sS]`, and matches a backslash, `s` and `S` chars.

However, in POSIX regex standard, `.` matches *any* chars including line break chars thus there is no need using `[\s\S]` workaround.

Comment: but, on a online clang compiler, [the code is working as expected](https://rextester.com/KJI53953).  I am sorry i can not find the compiler as the same as my computer.  On my computer, the compiler is __Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)__

Comment: @user1927896 Your is POSIX for sure judging by the behavior. Check [here](https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292).